# Securing an "open" web service without HTTPS or private shared key

Tags: web-services, security, encryption

I am producing a web service which will allow any third party "device" to communicate with it. Each device has a reasonably unusual string to identify itself and uses the web service to store data against this id. However, this allows someone who wishes to game the service to scan through and guess device ids and store malicious data against them.

The device itself using this web service is relatively "dumb" and doesn't offer a suitable interface for data entry, so a password or any form of entry on the client is not available.

As this web service is open for anyone who wishes to produce a device of this nature to use, I can't increase security with the use a private key as this would be publicly defined in a specification. Also due to the simplistic nature of the device and it's IP/HTTP stack, HTTPS is unsuitable for this implementation.

To the best of my knowledge I can't see a way of using a privately shared key in this operation. To this extent, I believe it be impossible to secure a system of this nature, but I am wondering if some other methods which I've yet to find may help me secure this system somewhat?

Comment: Is using long, random IDs for each device out of the question? That would be very imperfect as well if the ID can't be changed, but still much better than being able to guess IDs

Comment: Yes, suitably long device IDs are definitely one step to improve this situation. One concern, however, is that any 3rd party can create their own device and therefore their own identifiers. Therefore some kind of vendor ID name-spacing may be required to avoid collisions.

Comment: If they use a 128-bit GUID (again assuming they use a good algorithm), the likelihood of two vendors coming up with the same device ID is so infinitesimally small as to be negligible. The idea of GUIDs is to allow everybody in the world to produce as many GUIDs as they could possible want for the next hundred years, and have no two generated GUIDs end up being the same. A bigger problem would be that someone could "listen" to the GUID of a device, and later pretend to be that device. That's why you need a public key system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't use a public/private key pair?

You could publish the server's public key with the specification, and require each device to generate a random public/private key pair for itself. The device could encrypt its public key with the server's public key and send it to the server. The server could use its private key to decrypt the device's public key, and then assume that nobody else could decrypt any message that the server encrypts using that public key. The server therefore registers that public key as the device's ID.

If you set up some kind of session, the server can retain the device's public key associated with that session. If not, some defined portion of any message sent from the device to the server must include the device's public key encrypted this way, so that the server can know which device sent the message.

Any message sent to the server will be encrypted with both the client's private key (so the server knows this device sent it) and the server's public key (so only the server can read it). Messages sent to the device will be encrypted with the server's private key (so the client knows the server sent it) and the client's public key (so only the client can read it). Only you know your private key, and only they know their private key, so everything's secure as long as you (and they) use good seeding and encryption algorithms.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I understand this (my memory of Network Security lectures from university are failing me spectacularly this week...) This method doesn't prevent MITM attacks as I could just replicate what another device is doing. Though, I'm realising, MITM protection is likely impossible in what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually, the man-in-the-middle will only ever see your public key. They can't even decrypt the client's public key without knowing your private key. Even if they knew the client's public key, they can't decrypt the messages the client sends because they won't have your private key, and they can't decrypt the messages you send because they won't have the client's private key. That's the beauty of public key cryptography.

Comment: The only real potential for a security hole would lie with the device manufacturers, since they could potentially set up the device to communicate with their own gateway, and serve as a man-in-the-middle. But it's unreasonable to expect to be able to protect clients from the manufacturer of their device. If you can assume the device manufacturer will follow your specs and use an good algorithm for generating unguessable seeds, this strategy will give you very good security.

Comment: Got it. Really wish I'd got more sleep to stay awake in those lectures... Thanks!

Comment: There are some other issues to keep in mind. If someone captures an entire encrypted message and re-sends it, even if they don't know what it contains, you need to make sure it doesn't mess up your data. Also, many public-key systems just use the public keys for an initial handshake while they agree on a private key to use for the remainder of the session. Anyway, the point is that it is possible to have good security in the situation you describe: you just need to read a good book on it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try some simple challenge-response system, where the server sends a random string of bytes to the device. The device uses some known ID (ideally not the public one) and some hash like algorithm to produce a response.

This will only protect you from people without access to your devices, though.

Comment: This would certainly be a possibility. There is an "ideal" use case that the device should "just work" out the box without the requirement to go to any form of input page on another machine to verify the communication beforehand. I'm quickly learning that the "ideal" use case and security are not necessarily the friendliest of neighbours...

Answer (score 0):

If "guessing" device IDs is your only concern, make the device IDs unguessable? For instance, use the result of HMAC-SHA256 with a vendor-private key and serial number as the payload. Not even *you* would need a copy of the vendor's key.

That wouldn't be terribly useful though, as the device's network connection is probably sniffable thus its ID could be trivially captured over the wire. A secret key element *must* be present on the device, therefore. But this is where I get slightly confused - your concern over using a shared private key seems to be logistical, rather than whether the device can actually support it (implying that it does have some crypto) - yet you can't use HTTPS? What kind of limitations does the device have (memory/CPU/storage)?

Comment: The implementation is likely to be a very simple "baked on" chip setup, the issue with HTTPS is not necessarily limited to resources but also complexity and cost. It's still standing up as the only reasonable option currently...

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind.

First, use a non-guessable device id.  Something as simple as a base64 encoded guid would work.

Second you should require that the data being passed to your web service is encrypted using a public key.  Your private key would then be required to decrypt the data.

This would ensure that even if they have a listener watching the data come across, they wouldn't be able to grab a different device id.  Also, with a non-guessable ID they wouldn't be able to affect other device accounts.